# VB6 Compile error - User-defined type not defined

Tags: vb6

I looked over all the answers on the SO and none of the solutions have worked.
I have this code:

```
  Option Explicit
  Private mobjPersistenceDatabase As SPADSInt.CPersistDatabase
```

---

```
Private Function InitializeDatabases() As Boolean

Dim objPersistDatabase As CPersistDatabase
.....
Dim udtSystemConfigurationParameters As SystemConfigurationParameters ---*ERROR*
```

**SPADSInt** is AciveX DLL added to project references.
**CPersistDatabase** is one of SPADSInt Classes.
**SystemConfigurationParameters** is one of CPersistDatabase members.

When i compile it gives me error 'User-defined type not defined'.
I have reference added for the SPADSInt in my references and if i look up Properties/Methods for the CPersistDatabase it shows all the classes available, but SystemConfigurationParameters does not show up.
Any ideas?

EDIT: post view from object browser
[image]

[image]

EDIT2: This same code works just fine in other solution. I tried replicating references/components and still it would not work.

Comment: should it be `SPADSInt.SystemConfigurationParameters` as it is for `CPersistDatabase` further up?  or it may just be defined inside some other Type/Class

Comment: the first image indicates that `SystemConfigurationParameters` is a member of `SPADSInt.CPersistDatabase` hence `...As SPADSInt.CPersistDatabase.SystemConfigurationParameters` just like when you declared `mobjPersistenceDatabase As SPADSInt.CPersistDatabase` using the dot operator

Comment: yes it is one of the 5 members

Comment: but that means the fully qualified type name is `SPADSInt.CPersistDatabase.SystemConfigurationParameters` try using that with your `Dim` statement.

Comment: if i write full qualified name it tells me 'Type mismatch'

Comment: First shot says `Property SystemConfigurationParameters As String`. Why are you trying to use `SystemConfigurationParameters` as a type? This is not a class name, it's the `CPersistDatabase` that is a class which contains properties (and methods) like `SystemConfigurationParameters`, etc.

Comment: Presumably this should be: `Dim sSystemConfigurationParameters As String`
`sSystemConfigurationParameters = objPersistDatabase.SystemConfigurationParameters`

Comment: If i do it as you say, it throws an error 'Invalid use of property'